# Соцсети, предоставляющие API для работы с диалогами

Tags: android, соцсети

Нужно максимальное количество различных соцсетей (в том числе китайских), у которых есть англоязычная документация и которые позволяют работать с диалогами (получение списка диалогов, получение сообщений из кокретного диалога, отправка сообщений)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: А что ты хочешь от сообщества #ХэшКод ?

Comment: Меня интересует максимальный список соцсетей. Есть много достаточно экзотических для нашей страны соцсетей, которые тем не менее популярны в мире. Может быть кто-то работал с ними и знает конкретные сети, предоставляющие такое API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял, Вы хотите в итоге написать приложение которое будет взаимодействовать с социальными сетями.
Почему бы Вам не использовать универсальный интерфейс для работы с социальными сетями.
Вот [OneALL API](https://docs.oneall.com/api/).

[image: OneALL]